# How do I make a lock that allows only ONE thread to read from the resource?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a file that holds an integer ID value. Currently reading the file is protected with `ReaderWriterLockSlim` as such:

```
    public int GetId()
    {
        _fileLock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();
        int id = 0;
        try {
            if(!File.Exists(_filePath))
                CreateIdentityFile();

            FileStream readStream = new FileStream(_filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(readStream);
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            sr.Close();
            readStream.Close();
            id = int.Parse(line);
            return int.Parse(line);
        }
        finally {
            SaveNextId(id);     // increment the id 
            _fileLock.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that subsequent actions after `GetId()` might fail. As you can see the `GetId()` method increments the ID every single time, disregarding what happens after it has issued an ID. The issued ID might be left hanging (as said, exceptions might occur). As the ID is incremented, some IDs might be left unused.

So I was thinking of moving the `SaveNextId(id)` out, remove it (the `SaveNextId()` actually uses the lock too, except that it's `EnterWriteLock`). And call it manually from outside after all the required methods have executed. That brings out another problem - multiple threads might enter the `GetId()` method before the `SaveNextId()` gets executed and they might all receive the same ID.

I don't want any solutions where I have to alter the IDs after the operation, correcting them in any way because that's not nice and might lead to more problems.

I need a solution where I can somehow callback into the FileIdentityManager (that's the class that handles these IDs) and let the manager know that it can perform the saving of the next ID and then release the read lock on the file containing the ID.

Essentialy I want to replicate the relational databases autoincrement behaviour - if anything goes wrong during row insertion, the ID is not used, it is still available for use but it also never happens that the same ID is issued. Hopefully the question is understandable enough for you to provide some solutions..

*UPDATE: Please see the comments to the answers for more details about the behaviour I want*

Comment: I assume that it is a bad thing for you to have non-sequential IDs?

Comment: If you want a lock that just allows a single thread at a time, why don't you use a `lock`? I just read the title rather than the question though!!!

Comment: I will do with those that happen as a result of deletions. But I don't want to waste them on unsuccesful file saves, unsuccesful type casts, etc. I have it working now but this issue with nonsequential IDs showed itself quickly and because IDs are exposed in the UI, it looks ugly. Two concurrent content items might have IDs that are 10 numbers apart or more.

Comment: maybe I should note that reading and writing should be 'tied' together somehow and both locked together..I don't know if that's the right terminology..

Comment: If you stop expsoing IDs to the UI the problem is solved too. If you need sequential numbers, don't call them ID.

Comment: The IDs are used in an ASP.NET MVC application routes much like SO's IDs for questions the only difference being the backend datastore is not relational but XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Essentialy I want to replicate the
>   relational databases autoincrement
>   behaviour - **if anything goes wrong**
>   during row insertion, **the ID is not
>   used, it is still available for use**
>   but it also never happens that the
>   same ID is issued. Hopefully the
>   question is understandable enough for
>   you to provide some solutions.

Generally speaking that is not the behavior that I've observed. When you insert a row into table with an autoincrement inside a transaction and its rolled back you've lost the ID.

So in my opinion the way you've implemented this is the correct behavior.

**Update**
The only way you can ensure that you "don't want to waste them on unsuccesful file saves, unsuccesful type casts, etc." Is to change the scope of your blocking code to block from the moment you request a new ID until your save is complete and on failure to rollback the increment to the ID.

This will drastically reduce the level of parallelism you can achieve.

If you want to keep the potential for parallelism higher, you should check everything you can before you request an ID e.g. check types and format errors.

Obviously some things like external errors (IO exceptions) you simply cannot do anything about.

Comment: Ok, that could be true I guess (should go check it out again) but now I really want to solve my issue, because it should be possible especially since we control the behaviour, where in SQL Server we can't do much about it...

Comment: All right, I understand you a little better now. I decided I will use a lock, as proposed by @WraithNath but do it in the repository. The lock block will contain the try..catch block and the try will contain the GetId(), additional calls and then the SaveNextId(). Both GetId() and SaveNextId() will stay as they are now, with ReaderWriterLockSlim. However, I have a question. How is this all affected by the fact that this is an ASP.NET MVC application and I also use Ninject to create repository with the InRequestScope() option, if you know what I mean?

Answer (score 2):

```
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();

    public int GetId()   
    {
      lock(_lock)
      {
        //You code to get ID here
      }
    }
```

Comment: I guess when the code to get the ID finishes the lock immediatelly unlocks and another thread can enter? Could be before we know what happened to writing?

Comment: Yes, the code will unlock and allow another thread to enter when the code runs outside of the lock scope. You can put any logic you want inside the lock to work out what your next id is going to be, and whether to save it back or not. But as long as this method is used throughout the application only one thread can pass through it at a time.

Comment: the thing is my GetId() method is called from the repository that handles data access and insertion. It requests an ID from the FileIdentityManager class then constructs the object (including ID assignment) that will get serialized into XML. When an exception happens during serialization, the ID should be rolled back, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you see in your database is possible because the ID generation and row insertion are atomic.  If you want to have this behavior in your application, then I suggest you only get the ID immediately before storing the data.  This will reduce your "transaction scope" to the minimum possible window, and should prevent any exceptions from interfering.

If for some bad reason this isn't possible, an alternative might be to have an "ID broker" that caches the ID counter.  It would read the current counter from the file, increment it by some number (say 100), then hand out successive IDs to all callers through a single-threaded method.  When it has handed out all 100, it updates the file again.  At shutdown, it would write the file one last time, using the last value it handed out.  The only problem then is if your system crashes you wind up with a gap in your IDs, but there are ways to compensate for that.